# Seperate by loose parts

Tags: mesh

I have just tried to do the "separate by loose parts" option and I think there might be too many objects to separate so blender just crashes. Is there anyway I can do this without it crashing?

Thanks,
Dan

[image]

These are the blocks here  ^ ^ ^ ^

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on it? If yes You should turn them off for a moment.

Comment: no, they are literally just blocks and there are about 50-100 of them they had arrays, that's why there are so many. im trying to separate the arrays

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: I just tried it on 1000 cubes, generated from 3 arrays. Applied the arrays then `separate by loose parts` it took a while but it did work.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are having troubles with doing this in one operation you may have better luck by breaking it into smaller pieces.

1. In edit mode goto side view and Box select one or two levels. Press <kbd>B</kbd> to start box select mode.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to select vertices linked to what is selected, this ensures you keep each piece together.
3. Press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose Selection to separate the selected portion into a new object.
4. Repeat until you have separated the whole tower into smaller parts.
5. Select one of these smaller objects and go into edit mode.
6. Press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose by Loose Parts
7. Repeat for each part created above.

Answer (score 0):

Blender seems to be only using 2 cores for this operation, hence the possible crashes if you are running a lower spec machine.

tried a 40^3 of cubes and barely used over 2GB of ram, but crunched 2cores/4threads for over 30mins.

for further detail, the usage on those 2 cores being used goes from 0% to 100% constantly [image: this is what is looks like on a 8core/16thread cpu]

Comment: I don't think this answer improves a lot... since the question is more than 7 years old and has an (already accepted) 7 year old answer... do you even know if the CPU usage today works the same like it did on Blender 2.70 or 2.70a?